# Ubuntu Server 22.04 Problems after 3/8/23 update

Tags: server, 22.04

I've been using Linux for quite a while now and use Ubuntu 22.04 server for my homelab project.

Yesterday, 3rd August '23, I ran the `$ sudo apt update` followed by `$ sudo apt full-upgrade` and when it had finished updating the system showed that the kernel had been updated and the system needed to reboot, I rebooted the system.

Ever since the update and reboot, I can no longer ssh into my system. It just hangs so I logged into my system locally and when I run `$ sudo apt update` I get failed to fetch and temporary failure. I'm not sure what's going on as I  can still log into my docker containers and they are still running and working online but the main system itself seems to be off.

Sorry for lack of info as I'm really struggling with where to start with this

I have some more information below, once again thank you for taking the time to read this and a huge thank you for the replies.

On boot up here what is shown.

```
Failed to start uncomplicated firewall

cloud-init [6224] - cc_final_message.py[WARNING] : Used fallback datasource
```

After login

```
Failed to connect to https://changelings.Ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
```

After trying to run sudo apt update

% counter not moving when trying to connect

```
Temporary failure resolving 'dl.cloudsmith.io'

Temporary failure resolving 'download.docker.com'

Temporary failure resolving 'ppa.lauchpadcontent.net'

Temporary failure resolving 'nvidia.github.io'

Temporary failure resolving 'db.archive.Ubuntu.com'

Temporary failure resolving 'db.archive.Ubuntu.com

Temporary failure resolving 'db.archive.Ubuntu.com'
```

Tried $sudo systemctl restart networking

```
Failed to restart networking.service: Unit networking.service not found
```

Tried ping google.com

```
Ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Checked /etc/netplan
$sudo nano 00-installer-config.yaml

## This is the network config written by 'subiquity'

network:
ethernets:
enp0s25
addresses:
-  192.168.1.79/24
nameservers:
addresses:
-  1.1.1.1
-  1.0.0.1
-  8.8.8.8
search:   []
routes:
-  to: default
via: 192.168.1.1
version:  2

And everything looks normal in here, I really don't want to reinstall and start again as I have put a lot of work in but at the moment I really don't know where to start.

Comment: "*when I run $sudo apt update I get failed to fetch and temporary failure*" It's hard to tell from such a limited description, but 'failed to fetch' and 'temporary failure in name resolution' are common networking problems. I would suggest reviewing your logs for more details on what the problem might be. Perhaps a bit of network troubleshooting.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info, was hoping it was something simple that has happened to other uses after this update (probably is to someone else lol) I have written down some more info in hopes someone can help as I really do not want to reinstall and start again as I have done so much work and finally got things working that I could not before.